# Convertir Codigo VB.Net a PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

Este código *VB.Net* se encarga de encriptar una contraseña.

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal clave As String) As String
    ' Defino variables
    Dim indice As Integer = 1
    Dim largo As Integer = 0
    Dim final As String = ""
    largo = Len(Trim(clave))
    Dim caracteres(largo) As String
    For indice = 1 To largo
        caracteres(indice) = Mid(clave, indice, 1)
        caracteres(indice) = Chr(Asc(caracteres(indice)) + indice)
        final = final & caracteres(indice)
    Next indice
        Return final
End Function
```

Y este seria el código en *PHP* que hice pero estoy fallando en algún lugar ya que no obtengo el resultado deseado.

```
public static function encryption($clave){
    $indice = 1;
    $largo = 0;
    $final = '';

    $largo = strlen(trim($clave));
    $caracteres = array();
    for ($indice; $indice <= $largo; $indice++) { 
        $caracteres[$indice] = substr($clave, $indice, 1);
        $caracteres[$indice] = chr(ord($caracteres[$indice]) + $indice);
        $final = $final.$caracteres[$indice];
    }
    return $final;
}
```

> Un ejemplo seria que en *VB.Net* la clave **`12345`** se encripta en `**2468`**, y en *PHP* la misma clave se encripta en **`3579\u0005`**.

Estaré agradecido con todos los que puedan ayudarme a descubrir en que estoy fallando y como puedo solucionarlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cambia substr($clave, $indice, 1) por $clave[$indice-1]
- También puedes hacer substr($clave, $indice - 1, 1)

```
function encryption($clave){
    $indice = 1;
    $largo = 0;
    $final = '';

    $largo = strlen(trim($clave));
    $caracteres = array();
    for ($indice; $indice <= $largo; $indice++) { 
        $caracteres[$indice] = substr($clave, $indice - 1, 1);
        $caracteres[$indice] = chr(ord($caracteres[$indice]) + $indice);
        $final = $final.$caracteres[$indice];
    }
    return $final;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, acabo de aplicar el cambio y el resultado se acerco mas pero no es el correcto, el resultado en php con los cambios fue 13579

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos, que pena error mío, ya quedo solucionado

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pero te comento que con tu primera solución  haciendo este cambio $caracteres[$indice] = chr(ord($caracteres[$indice]) + ($indice + 1)) tambien funciona